# How to measure cylinder volume by water weight

Tags: fluid-statics, gas, volume

I'm trying to determine the volume of a cylinder ( 25 cc approximately) in a precise way.

First I'm measure the weight of the empty cylinder.
Then, I'm add water to the cylinder until the water filling the level of the cylinder and i measure the weight of the  cylinder+water.
I use analytics weight with accuracy of digits.
In this case, the last digit is always change due to the water evaporation and gets different results for the same measure.

Can you suggest me a different way to determine the volume of the cylinder or any idea how overcome the water evaporation.

Comment: Welcome to physics SE! The evaporation is unlikely to play a role here, the rate of mass loss should be quite low. Depending on the shape of the cylinder I would rather worry about surface tension and curvature of the free surface. In either case: What accuracy are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What sort of accuracy are you seeking?

Answer (score 0):

The density of water varies with temperature and with salinity. Unless you control these factors very carefully (e.g. always use distilled water at the same temperature) you are unlikely to get a precision very much better than one part in a hundred with this method.